# How to filter the Maximum number of occurrences of objects with the same id using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I need to find out the `newsId` which has received maximum comments.

I have created the `News` class in which I created method variables, constructor, getters and setters.

I've created `Main` class to write the logic in java 8 using streams.

I'm struck at implementing the `Predicate` interface in filtering out the `newsId` which has maximum number of count in the list of `News` objects.

```
public class News {
    int newsId;
    String postByUser;
    String commentByUser;
    String comment;

    public News(int newsId, String postByUser, String commentByUser, String comment) {
        this.newsId = newsId;
        this.postByUser = postByUser;
        this.commentByUser = commentByUser;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public int getNewsId() {
        return newsId;
    }

    public void setNewsId(int newsId) {
        this.newsId = newsId;
    }

    public String getPostByUser() {
        return postByUser;
    }

    public void setPostByUser(String postByUser) {
        this.postByUser = postByUser;
    }

    public String getCommentByUser() {
        return commentByUser;
    }

    public void setCommentByUser(String commentByUser) {
        this.commentByUser = commentByUser;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}

class Main {

    static List < News > news = Arrays.asList(
        new News(1, "fb_Userpost", "fb_Usercomment", "comment1"),
        new News(2, "insta_userpost", "insta_usercomment", "comment2"),
        new News(1, "whatsapp_userpost", "whatsapp_usercomment", "comment3"),
        new News(1, "whatsapp_userpost", "whatsapp_usercomment", "comment3"),
        new News(3, "whatsapp_userpost", "whatsapp_usercomment", "comment3")
    );
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //   Predicate<News> pr = s -> s
        news.stream()
            .filter(pr)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(s - > System.out.println(s.getNewsId()));
    }
```

Comment: Rather than using `filter().collect()...` to find the max element, there's a very convenient method available: `Stream<T>::max(Comparator<T>)`. `Stream#filter` is for using a predicate to either include or exclude results from the downstream operations (an intermediate operation), not for comparing elements within the stream (a [_stateful_ intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)).

Answer (score 2):

#### Result - a single newsId

> I need to find out the `newsId` which has received maximum comments.

You can't achieve it by using a `filter()` alone. And it's not necessary to utilize `filter()` operation for that at all.

To find the **most frequent news**, you need to accumulate the data. Method `collect()` should be responsible for that, and not the `filter()`.

The most obvious option is to create an intermediate `Map` which will contain a count for each `newsId`. To do that, you can use a combination of collectors [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()).

Then you can create a stream over the map entries and pick the entry with the highest value using `max()` as a terminal operation.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    news.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // creating an intermediate Map<Integer, Long>
            News::getNewsId,            // map's key
            Collectors.counting()       // value
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()               // creating a stream over the map's entries
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // picking the entry with the highest value -> result: Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)            // transforming the optional result Optional<Integer> 
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);   // printing the result if optional is not empty
}
```

With your sample data, this code will produce the output `1`.

#### Result - a List of newsId having the highest frequency

In order to address the case when there could be several `newsId` having the same number of occurrences, you can build *a *custom collector*.

The initial idea is the same a described above, but instead `max()` operation, this time we would apply `collect()` on the stream of map entries and a *custom collector* will be provided as an argument.

To create a custom collector, we can utilize the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

The logic behind the *custom collector* provided below is following:

- `supplier` - intermediate results (*map entries*) are being stored in a `Queue`.
- `accumulator` - if the next stream *element* has the same *frequency count* (*the value of a map entry*) as the first element in the *queue*, or the *queue* is empty, then it gets added into the *queue*. If the *count* of the next *element* is lower, it would be ignored. And if the *count* is higher, the *queue* gets cleaned, and the next *element* will be added.
- `combiner` The two *queues* obtained while executing the stream in parallel would be combined using almost the same logic as described above for *accumulator*.
- `finisher` - this function transforms the *queue* of map entries into a list of `newsId`.

**Note** that such an implementation allows to make only a *single iteration* over the entry set, and this performance advantage is a justification for its complexity.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    news.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            News::getNewsId,
            Collectors.counting()
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            ArrayDeque::new,
            (Queue<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> queue, Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry) -> {
                if (queue.isEmpty() || queue.element().getValue().equals(entry.getValue())) {
                    queue.add(entry);
                } else if (queue.element().getValue() < entry.getValue()) {
                    queue.clear();
                    queue.add(entry);
                }
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                if (left.isEmpty() || !right.isEmpty()
                    && right.element().getValue() > left.element().getValue())
                    return right;
                if (right.isEmpty() || left.element().getValue() > right.element().getValue())
                    return left;
                
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            },
            queue -> queue.stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

static List<News> news = Arrays.asList( // News `1` & `2` are the most frequent
    new News(1, "fb_Userpost", "fb_Usercomment", "comment1"),
    new News(2, "insta_userpost", "insta_usercomment", "comment2"),
    new News(2, "insta_userpost", "insta_usercomment", "comment2"),
    new News(2, "insta_userpost", "insta_usercomment", "comment2"),
    new News(1, "whatsapp_userpost", "whatsapp_usercomment", "comment3"),
    new News(1, "whatsapp_userpost", "whatsapp_usercomment", "comment3"),
    new News(3, "whatsapp_userpost", "whatsapp_usercomment", "comment3")
);
```

*Output:*

```
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me the solution. One more additional question is If I'm giving equal number of occurrence i.e., For example 
newsId=1  //occurs twice,
newsId=2  //occurs twice
The above logic returns only newsId=1 but not newsId=2 which also occurs equal in number with 1. How can I print the values which occurs equally as well. Thanks!

Comment: @YashTumu So you want a list of the most frequent `newsId`s, correct?

Comment: Yes! But it is popping out the first value itself

Comment: @YashTumu I've updated the answer (see the version that makes use of the custom collector). An explanation of the collector's logic would be added in a minute.

Comment: @YashTumu It'll be nicer if you would add this clarification with an updated example to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, count the number of times each `newsId` is referenced. Then, find the maximum count. Finally, keep only those identifiers with the maximum count.

```java
Map<Integer, Long> countByNewsId = news.stream()
    .map(News::getNewsId)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
Long max = countByNewsId.values().stream().max(Long::compareTo).orElse(null);
countByNewsId.values().removeIf(Predicate.isEqual(max).negate());
Set<Integer> maxCommentedNewsIds = countByNewsId.keySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that only uses a single stream pass although speed wise it's probably slightly slower (I haven't benchmarked it) than Alexander's solution however it is far shorter.

```java
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

news.stream()
        .map(News::getNewsId)
        .collect(
                teeing(
                        groupingBy(identity(), counting()),
                        collectingAndThen(groupingBy(identity(), counting()), map -> Collections.max(map.values())),
                        (frequencyMap, max) -> {
                            frequencyMap.values().removeIf(v -> v != max.longValue());
                            return frequencyMap.keySet();
                        }
                )
        ).forEach(System.out::println);
```